# For inside another For, Next without For Error

Tags: excel, vba

```vb
For i = 0 To lQtd
    ...

    confemails = Split(EnviarPara, ";")

    For j = 0 To UBound(confemails)
        If EmailValido(confemails(j)) Then

             Next j
        
        Else
            MsgBox "O e-mail" & confemails(j) & "Na linha" & i & "da tabela, foi digitado incorretamente, favor corrigir e enviar novamente."

            Next i

        EndIf

        SendEmail

Next i
```

My problem is in the second `For`.

The idea is to go through the list of email addresses (confemails) to make sure all email addresses are in the correct format.

If so: send email
If not: send a message and go to next list of email addresses

[image: compilation Error: Next without For]

> Compilation Error: Next without For

Comment: Are you checking the validity all the email addresses before sending, so one email for each value of i

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have the Next inside the If block.  Instead just do the Else:

```
For i = 0 To lQtd
    ...

    confemails = Split(EnviarPara, ";")

    For j = 0 To UBound(confemails)
        If Not EmailValido(confemails(j)) Then
            MsgBox "O e-mail" & confemails(j) & "Na linha" & i & "da tabela, foi digitado incorretamente, favor corrigir e enviar novamente."
            Exit For
        End If        
        SendEmail
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

```vb
For i = 0 To lQtd
    ...

    confemails = Split(EnviarPara, ";")
    msg = ""
    For j = 0 To UBound(confemails)
        If Not EmailValido(confemails(j)) Then
             msg = msg & " " & confemails(j)
        End If
    Next

    If msg = "" Then
        Sendmail
    Else    
        MsgBox "O e-mail Na linha " & i & " da tabela, foi digitado incorretamente, favor corrigir e enviar novamente." & msg
    End If
Next
```